# Using a non-static data member as parameter

Tags: c++

I have this code:

```
#include <set>
#include <vector>

struct Comp {
    const std::vector<int> & xs;

    Comp(const std::vector<int> & xs): xs(xs) {}

    bool operator(int a, int b) const {
        // Sort based on data in xs.
    } 
};

class Foo {

public:
    Foo();

private:
    std::vector<int> xs;
    std::set<std::size_t, Comp(xs)> ys;

};
```

I would like to use a custom compare function for my set that depends on another data member. In my case, the set contains indexes into the vector and the compare function just checks the value at the index and sorts based on that value. Just sorting the vector is not an option.

Every time I update a value in the vector, I `erase` and then `insert` the index that corresponds to the value in the vector to keep the set updated as well.

Right now I get the error message: `error: invalid use of non-static data member 'xs'`. What is the best way to achive what I want?

Comment: 1. `bool operator()(int a, int b) const` 

2. `std::set<int, Comp>`

Comment: If changes to `xs` causes the order of elements that is already in `ys` to change, then you have undefined behaviour.

Comment: @Croessmah Do I not have to specify which vector I want my compare to be based on using the constructor? Does this automatically use the xs in my class?

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/W9Er5s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either provide the reference to `xs` to `Comp` and `Comp` to `ys`

- in the member-initialisation-list of the constructor
- or once for all where the `ys` member is declared.

**!!! if you change the content of `xs` while `ys` is not empty, then `ys` will certainly become unusable !!!**

In this adaptation of your code, you can see that `ys` is ordered according to `xs`.

```
/**
  g++ -std=c++17 -o prog_cpp prog_cpp.cpp \
      -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -Wno-sign-conversion \
      -g -O0 -UNDEBUG -fsanitize=address,undefined
**/

#include <iostream>

#include <set>
#include <vector>

struct Comp {
    const std::vector<int> & xs;

    Comp(const std::vector<int> & xs): xs(xs) {}

    bool operator()(int a, int b) const {
        return size(xs)%2==0 ? a<b : b<a; // Sort based on data in xs.
    } 
};

class Foo {

public:
    Foo(std::vector<int> v)
    : xs{std::move(v)}
    , ys{Comp{xs}}
    {}

// private:

    std::vector<int> xs;
    std::set<int, Comp> ys;
    // std::set<int, Comp> ys{Comp{xs}}; // or once for all
};

int
main()
{
  auto f1=Foo{{1, 2, 3}};
  for(auto i=0; i<20; ++i)
  {
    f1.ys.insert(i%7);
  }
  for(const auto &e: f1.ys) { std::cout << e << ' '; } std::cout << '\n';

  auto f2=Foo{{1, 2, 3, 4}};
  for(auto i=0; i<20; ++i)
  {
    f2.ys.insert(i%7);
  }
  for(const auto &e: f2.ys) { std::cout << e << ' '; } std::cout << '\n';
  return 0;
}
/*
6 5 4 3 2 1 0 
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 
*/
```

Comment: Thanks I will try this approach. I edited my question to explain how I'm using the vector to sort my set. I think in that case the set does not become unusable if I change the contents of the vector.